# Contexto del filtro DAX en Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tengo una hoja de cálculo simple para controlar el suministro de combustible.

3 columnas: Fecha de llenado \ Matrícula \ KM en el odómetro al llenar.

Quiero montar una medición para saber cuánto se disparó en KM.

Para eso, necesitaba tomar el KM más grande: el KM más pequeño para cada PLACA (automóvil diferente) y sumarlo todo.

El problema es que no puedo romper con coche dentro de la medida, a menos que lo explique filtrando coche por coche. Sin embargo, se pueden registrar otros autos y no será posible actualizar la medida.

Si uso esta medida aquí:

```
KM rodado = CALCULATE (SUM (ftSupplements [Km]), LASTDATE (ftSupplements [Fecha de suministro])) - CALCULATE (SUM (ftSupplements [Km]), FIRSTDATE (ftSupplements [Fecha de suministro]))
```

Utilizo la columna de fecha para obtener el KM en las fechas más pequeñas y más grandes que aparecen, restan y suman.

Si pongo esta medida en una tabla con la columna de la placa, el resultado de cada placa aparece de la manera correcta. Necesitaba encontrar una manera de agregar esos valores.

Answer (score 0):

No se si lo he entendido correctamente, entiendo que deseas conocer un valor total, independientemente de que exista un filtro aplicado para un vehículo. Si eso es así necesitas, dentro de la fórmula DAX, eliminar dicho filtro con la función `ALL()`.

Por ejemplo:

```
KM rodado = 
VAR KM_INICIALES = CALCULATE (SUM (ftSupplements [Km]), LASTDATE (ftSupplements [Fecha de suministro]), ALL(ftSupplements)) 
VAR KM_FINALES = CALCULATE (SUM (ftSupplements [Km]), FIRSTDATE (ftSupplements [Fecha de suministro]), ALL(ftSupplements))

RETURN
KM_FINALES  - KM_INICIALES
```